# ts-node cannot find npm module discord-api-types

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, discord.js, ts-node

When attempting to run discord.js file `deploy-commands.ts` with the command `ts-node deploy-commands.ts` ts-node produces the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js/node_modules/discord-api-types'
Require stack:
- /Users/Cameron/discord.js/discordjs-guides/deploy-commands.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:679:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Cameron/discord.js/discordjs-guides/deploy-commands.ts:4:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1455:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1458:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/Cameron/discord.js/discordjs-guides/deploy-commands.ts' ]
}
```

Despite `discord-api-types` appearing both in the node-modules folder and in package.json. The error is consistently reproduced after running `npm install discord-api-types` and npm resoding discord-api-types is up-to-date.

Package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^0.12.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.3.0",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.29.0",
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0"
  }
```

deploy-commands.ts:

```
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from "@discordjs/builders";
import { REST } from "@discordjs/rest";
import { version } from "discord.js";
import { Routes } from "discord.js/node_modules/discord-api-types";

const { token, guildID, clientID } = require('./process.json')

const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ping').setDescription('Replies with pong.'),
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('server').setDescription('Replies with server info.'),
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('user').setDescription('Replies with user info.'),
]
    .map(commands => JSON)

const rest = new REST({version: '9'}).setToken(token)

rest.put(Routes.applicationCommand(clientID, guildID), {body: { commands }})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully registered application commands')
    })
    .catch(console.error)
```

Comment: The `discord-api-types` is a sub package of discord.js so I think you just import from `discord-api-types` not `discord.js/node_modules/discord-api-types`

Comment: Replacing `discord.js/node_modules/discord-api-types` with `discord-api-types` results in ts producing the error `Cannot find module 'discord-api-types' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: Hmm this is strange. Try removing the package and install again with save flag

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change this code line:

```
import { Routes } from "discord.js/node_modules/discord-api-types";
```

To its version using because of this:

```
const rest = new REST({version: '9'}).setToken(token)
```

So you need to define the version you use, try changing your import to

```
import { Routes } from "discord-api-types/v9";
```

As I tried to my testing slash command files, you can do this kind of line too:

```
import { Routes } from "discord.js/node_modules/discord-api-types/v9";
```

I'm not using .ts so might not work but give it a shot